# маршрутизация wireguard внутри socks5

Tags: ubuntu, socks5, wireguard

у меня на VPS ubuntu установлен wireguard-server, клиент установлен на ubuntu и через вторую сетевую раздает интернет дальше по сети.

Проблема, часть сайтов не открываются с ip адреса wireguard-server и хотелось бы, чтобы VPS ubuntu ходила в интернет через socks5. Как это настроить?